# Filter strings across multiple columns with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks something like this.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,           ~x,  ~y,              ~z,  
  "N/A",            1,   "testSmith",    -100, 
  "N A",            3,   "NOt available", -99,
  "test Smith",     NA,  "test Smith",    -98,
  "Not Available", -99, "25",             -101,
  "test Smith",    -98, "28",             -1)
```

I would like to create a new data.table that keeps all the rows the string "test".

The final dataset should look something like this

```
  name           x y              z
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1 N/A            1 testSmith   -100
2 test Smith    NA test Smith   -98
3 test Smith   -98 28            -1
```

I could do this column by column like this

```
setDT(df)[name%like%"test"|y%like%"test"]
```

The problem with this approach is that I have hundreds of string variables and I would like to find a more compact approach. I tried the followings but they do not work

```
chvar <- keep(trai,is.character)%>%names()
setDT(df)[chvar%like%"test"]#error
setDT(df)[(chvar)%like%"test"]#error
setDT(df)[.(chvar)%like%"test"]#empty dt
```

Does someone know how I could do it in a quick and efficient way?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c('name', 'y')
setDT(df)

df[df[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%like%`, "test")), .SDcols = cols]]

#         name   x          y    z
#1:        N/A   1  testSmith -100
#2: test Smith  NA test Smith  -98
#3: test Smith -98         28   -1
```

In base R :

```
subset(df, Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], function(x) grepl('test', x))))
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(all_of(cols), ~grepl('test', .x))))
```

`lapply`/`across` returns a list of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values for all columns. It will return `TRUE` if `'test'` is present and `FALSE` if it is not present. When we use it in combination with `Reduce` and `|` it will give `TRUE` only of there is atleast one `TRUE` value in the row. If all the values in the row are `FALSE` it will returns `FALSE`. We select only those rows which has at least one `TRUE` value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option is using `grepl`

```
dt[rowSums(dt[, lapply(.SD, grepl, pattern = "test")]) > 0, .SDcols = .(name, y)]
```

such that

```
         name   x          y    z
1:        N/A   1  testSmith -100
2: test Smith  NA test Smith  -98
3: test Smith -98         28   -1
```